# How to increase the power of the motor control controller?

Tags: power, batteries, performance

There is an electric scooter, you need to increase the power by at least 10%, because with my light weight, it stops already when you raise 10 degrees. And I'm sure this is not the maximum that he is capable of. I enclose a photo of the motor, battery and controller. What are the options? I know how to solder a little.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Scooter Fitfiu Flying - made in Spain. Battery SAMSUNG 36V 4.4Ah.
Guys, I draw your attention to the fact that the question sounds HOW, but not "is it possible", and is it "safe". Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this appears to be a question about the use or repair of a product. You have presented nothing to indicate that you understand anything about the underlying design. There is nothing about what the manufacturer says about its capability to carry a weight up a grade. Knowing how to solder a little is of no value if you don't have the proper test equipment and experience to analyze the problem.

Comment: I would argue that is a question about how to modify/improve a product.

Comment: Yes its about modify and improve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the problem is to increase torque, the answer is to supply more current to the motor when climbing.

Whether any of the components are adequate for that task is another question. Your mext steps are to determine how much extra torque (therefore current) you need, and read the datasheets for all those components to determine which need replacing.